# Remote event receiver setting LastModifiedBy to "SharePoint Program"

Tags: sharepoint, csom

I have a remote event receiver, on a list, that fires every time an item is updated, and it works fine.

However the "Last modified by"-field on the item is set to "SharePoint program". I have tried setting the field to a specific value, but it seems do do no good, it still ends up as "SharePoint Program" (I guess that Update() automatically set the last modified again)

```
private static void RemoveMemberGroupFromItem(ListItem item, Group memberGroup, User modifyingUser)
    {
        var userToken = modifyingUser.LoginName;

        // Some changes on the item

        item.FieldValues[ModifiedByField] = userToken;
        item.Update();
    }
```

I tried setting properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties to a specific value as well; (the `vti_modifiedby`) but it didn't help either.

Answer (score -1):

If you use `item.SystemUpdate()` instead?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms461526.aspx

Comment: That is not available in CSOM